# Minitest controller sequence to assert changes to calculated variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

First test

```
assert_changes '@user_end.login_name' do
  post update_login_user_path(id: @user_end.id),  params: { user: { email: '', mobile_nation_id: 1, mobile: 876321 } }
end

"@user_end.login_name" didn't change.
Expected "end_consumer_email@mail.co" to not be equal to "end_consumer_email@mail.co".
```

Second test

```
post update_login_user_path(id: @user_end.id),  params: { user: { email: '', mobile_nation_id: 1, mobile: 876321 } }
assert_equal(39876321, @user_end.login_name)

Expected: 39876321
Actual: "end_consumer_email@mail.co"
```

Both are returning the fixture value and not the expected value, which is generated in practice in the application.  The controller action :

```
  if params[:user][:email].present? || params[:user][:mobile].present?
    set_user_login_name
  end
```

calls a method

```
  def set_user_login_name
    if !params[:user][:email].blank?
      params[:user][:login_name] = params[:user][:email].gsub(/\s+/, "")
    elsif !params[:user][:mobile_nation_id].blank? && !params[:user][:mobile].blank?
      @nation = Nation.where(id: params[:user][:mobile_nation_id]).first
      params[:user][:login_name] = @nation.phone_cc.to_s + params[:user][:mobile].to_s
      params[:user][:twilio_number] = '+' + @nation.phone_cc.to_s  + params[:user][:mobile].to_s
    else
      params[:user][:login_name] = ''
    end
    params[:user][:kee] = SecureRandom.alphanumeric(32)
    params[:user][:virtual_qr_code] = params[:user][:login_name] + params[:user][:kee]
  end
```

As the methods work in practice, it is clear I do not grasp how to properly use these two assertions.  I don not seem to be able to call the updated record *(whereas for a create `assert_equal('18831912200', User.last.login_name)` is straightforward)*

How can either one of them be cast to assert the above method?

Comment: try call `@user_end.reload` before `assert_equal` in the second test

Comment: OK,  that works, but I guess I am not understanding what the test is doing with the object being changed here.  I understand after the test, the objects are rolled back - so why the `reload`?

Comment: i guess a user record (which has id is `@user_end.id`) be saved some where in your controller action, right ?  but the instance `@user_end` in your test case is not updated, so you need to call `reload` to refresh